# How to point to the last item in an array

Tags: c++

As a small project I am trying to make a simple program that will write out a string backwards using a char array.

```
char line[] = "String";
char *endLine = &line[5]

cout << *endline << endl;
```

This program will compile and run but I am wondering if there is any way to do it so that it does not matter what the arrays length is. Such that is will always compile. I have tried:

```
char line[] = "String";

char *endLine = &line[sizeof(line)];

cout << *endLine << endl;
```

However every time I have compiled this it would not return a character.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In the example, `line` has a size of 7 chars!

Comment: If you use " " marks before text in a char array it counts the chars inside of it almost as a string, it does not include the quotation marks. When I would return the top on I would get out put as the letter g.

Comment: BTW, that means that in your first example, `endLine` doesn't point to the last element of the array! The last element of the array is a char with value zero.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thank you.

Comment: Neither of those attempts approaches printing a string backwards.

Answer (score 4):

Use std::string instead. That's much simpler to use and understand.

```
std::string line="String2";
if (!line.empty()){//avoid crashes for empty strings
    std::cout<<line[line.length()-1];
}
```

In C++11:

```
std::string line="String2";
if (!line.empty()){//avoid crashes for empty strings
    std::cout<<line.back();
}
```

Comment: In C++11 and later, `std::string` has a `back()` method that returns a reference to the last character (if not empty).

Answer (score 2):

You want to subtract 2 from the length, because of the nul terminator character:

```
char text[] = "Vanilla";
cout << text[sizeof(text) - 2] << "\n";
```

**Edit 1:** Note: corrected per comments.
Location `[sizeof(text)]` is out of bounds.
Location `[sizeof(text) - 1]` refers to the nul terminator.
Location `[sizeof(text) - 2]` refers to the last character, not nul.

Comment: Note that `sizeof()` only works in this example because of `sizeof(char)=1`. If you change the array to use a different multi-byte type, `sizeof()` alone won't work anymore. The generic way to get the number of elements in a fixed array regardless of the element type is to use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` instead, or [`std::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) in C++17 and later.

Comment: When I run this the program still isn't returning a value.

Comment: @JohnTedesco: that is because `text` is being initialized to include a null terminator, which `sizeof()` counts, so this code needs to subtract 2 instead of 1 to get the last character before the terminator ([demo](https://ideone.com/x6cPOd)). Thomas's claim to "*subtract 1 from the **length***" is correct, but `sizeof(text)` is the total byte size of the *whole array* including the terminator, it is not the **string length**.

Comment: @JohnTedesco That's because it's wrong. The size of `text` in the example is `8` (including the terminator). Therefore, size-1 yields 7. But as you know, zero-based indexing tells you `text[7]` is the nullchar terminator. The opening statement in this answer is correct, "You want to subtract 1 from the length" is indeed what you want to do. However, the code doens't do that. it subtracts 1 from the *size*, not the length (the latter doesn't normally doesn't consider counting the terminator).

Comment: I understand now that there is a nullchar terminator, but why is that there? There are no spaces or anything after the text. Also when working with this type of array are those always present?

Comment: @JohnTedesco:  By definition.  String literals are terminated by a '\0' or nul terminator.  This is inherited from the C language.

Comment: @JohnTedesco That is how C strings work... Imagine there was no terminating null character; the memory after the string could contain arbitrary values, so how would you want to determine, where it ends? This gets especially relevant if you only have a pointer to it via `char*`!

Comment: @JohnTedesco: string literals are always null terminated. When you initialize a fixed `char[]` array with a string literal, the compiler includes the null terminator in the array.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews *"out of bounds"* yes; I'd additionally refer to "exactly one past the array", as this is so important for pointer arithmetics...

Comment: @RemyLebeau _"The generic way to get the number of elements in a fixed array regardless of the element type"_ is `template <typename T, size_t N> size_t get_ur_size(const T (&)[N]) { return N; }`, not `sizeof` hacks that silently break in the presence of decay.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As I said: "*The generic way to get the number of elements **in a fixed array***", which doesn't apply when decay occurs. But whatever. What you showed is exactly what `std::size` does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Great! The standards committee must have been reading my SO answers :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The point is that the `sizeof` mechanism is dangerously error prone and as such "we" do not tend to recommend it. You don't have to wait for C++17 to get a thing like `std::size`, as you've pointed out

Answer (score 0):

Provided you get C strings of arbitrary length (e. g. via some C API: `char const* f(void);`), you could use `strlen`:

```
char const* array = f();
std::cout << array[strlen(array) - 1];
```

You *could* assign it to a `std::string` instead, getting back to Gabriel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49439877/1312382), but that would create a copy internally, some overhead you might prefer to spare if matter is as easy as in the given case...

This approach *would* work on the arrays as you provided them, too, however strlen is calculated at runtime whereas Thomas' [`sizeof` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49439909/1312382) (and the *better* alternatives discussed in the comments) is calculated at compile time (i. e. has no impact when running the program).

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
 string text="saeed";
for(int i=text.length()-1;i<text.length();i--){
    cout<<text[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I already solved this problem. Although your solution works well